# Invalid token from Facebook ACAccount after removing app permission from Facebook Control Panel

Tags: ios, facebook, acaccountstore

I can correctly log into Facebook using the ACAccountStore account.
But if I delete the app from the Facebook Control Panel (https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications), I get the following error when trying to get the user's friends :

```
{"error":
   {"message":"Error validating access token: The user has not authorized 
     application XXXXXXXX.",
   "type":"OAuthException","code":190,"error_subcode":458}}
```

If I delete the account from Settings, and re-login, the error goes away.

I'm using the following code to get the token, and use it in the requests. (snippet)

```
[self.store requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType
                               options:options
                            completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

   self.accounts = [self.store accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
        NSMutableArray *availableAccounts = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.account = self.accounts[0];

    self.username = self.account.username;
    self.userFullName = self.account.userFullName;
    self.authToken = self.account.credential.oauthToken;

}]
```

Comment: It the user deletes your app the access token will be invalidated. That is by design

Comment: After reinstalling the app

Comment: If I remove the app from fb control panel, and then reinstall my app in iOS I get a wrong token